# Make SQL databases go automatically into elastic pools

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops

I'm having some trouble using Azure's elastic pool feature. Right now, I have a SQL server with a bunch of databases that I want to store in an elastic pool to cut costs. My problem is that right now, everything is deployed in a very specific, non-negotiable way. Resource groups, storage accounts, and SQL servers are spun up with ARM templates and databases are added to the server with Microsoft's [Azure SQL Database Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeployment/DeploySqlAzure.ps1) function in VSTS. Everything I do should be automated for disaster recovery.

Is there a way to configure the server on creation so everything goes automatically into the elastic pool? Is there a way to change the [Azure SQL Database Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeployment/DeploySqlAzure.ps1) step so it adds the db to the pool and not just the server?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I ended up adding a powershell task to VSTS and running a simple json+script that took in the resource group, server name, pool name, and database names, then ran Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase.

Comment: There isn't the setting for Azure SQL Database Deployment task to add db to elastic pool.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT is there a UserVoice post to vote about that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a custom build step. Included the required parameters in a json and ran a powershell script that connected with

```
Initialize-AzurePowershellSupport -ConnectedServiceName $ConnectedServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$subscription = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionName #(Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionName
```

and then used `Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase`to move the database to an elastic pool.

Answer (score 2):

You can [manage SQL Database elastic pools using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool#manage-sql-database-elastic-pools-using-powershell) (e.g. Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase: Sets properties for a database, or moves an existing database into, out of, or between elastic pools.), so you can try to use Azure PowerShell step/task to move database to elastic pool.

Regarding ARM template, you can get it when creating SQL Database in azure portal:

[image]

On the other hand, there is an article about a template allows to deploy a new SQL Elastic Pool with its new associated SQL Server and new SQL Databases to assign to it: [Deploy a new SQL Elastic Pool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-sql-elastic-pool-create/)

Comment: Sure, that would've worked but everything needs to be automated for DRBC. I ended up getting it to work through powershell.